# Pass parameters to inner arrow function used with Playwright's evaluate

Tags: javascript, scope, playwright

I am using playwright at the moment, and want to write a function which contains an inner arrow function, something along the lines of

```
 async function setSearchDate(startDate='2021-12-07') {
    ....do something...

    const startDateAttribute = await page.$(searchStartDate);
    await startDateAttribute.evaluate(node => node.setAttribute('value', startDate));
```

but somehow the inner arrow function does not see startDate value.
the error I'm getting is      "elementHandle.evaluate: ReferenceError: startDate is not defined".

The code works well if I hardcode *startDate* value in the arrow function.
How can I pass that value?

Comment: What's the error that indicates it can't be seen? `startDate` is certainly in scope of the inner arrow function as posted.  If it couldn't be seen, you'd know it at compile time.

Comment: @danh the error is   "elementHandle.evaluate: ReferenceError: startDate is not defined"

Comment: @danh don't forget this is Playwright. The code won't run in the same execution context as the rest.

Comment: LOL, @CherryDT. Never heard of it. I for real thought the OP was supporting an artist by building code for them!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playwright pass variable into eval with JavaScript (Node)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284088/playwright-pass-variable-into-eval-with-javascript-node)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`evaluate` evaluates your function *in the page*, not in your code's context. You can access everything that exist in the page's execution environment (e.g. `window`, `document`, etc.) but nothing that exists in *your* execution environment (e.g. `startDate`). That's because in the page's context, there is no variable `startDate` (unless the page defined its own `window.startDate`...).

To pass parameters, you must make use of the `...args` - `evaluate` takes extra arguments which are all passed along to your function:

```js
await startDateAttribute.evaluate(
  (node, startDate) => node.setAttribute('value', startDate),
//       ^^^^^^^^^  2) extra argument(s) arrive here
//vvvvvvvvv         1) extra argument(s) getting passed in here
  startDate
)
```

See docs: [Evaluating JavaScript](https://playwright.dev/docs/evaluating/) (explaining this exact pitfall) and [`ElementHandle#evaluate`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-jshandle#js-handle-evaluate).

Comment: This works, and thank you for the documentation link! you're awesome!

Comment: Updated the docs link - I just realized Playwright is its own thing. Should work the same though.

Comment: Hmm, similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284088/playwright-pass-variable-into-eval-with-javascript-node

Comment: Right - linking as duplicate, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
await startDateAttribute.evaluate(function(node) { node.setAttribute('value', startDate) });
```

Comment: sadly it returns the same error:(