# How in Playwright get in evaluate data from arguments?

Tags: javascript, testing, e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-test

How in Playwright get in evaluate data from arguments?
page.evaluate: ReferenceError: d is not defined

```
async function testEv(d) {
  const data = await this.page.evaluate(function() {
    console.log('d from args is', d)
  })
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playwright pass variable into eval with JavaScript (Node)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284088/playwright-pass-variable-into-eval-with-javascript-node)

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass to the `evaluate` function a function that expects an argument. To avoid the confusion lets call it `c`, and then you pass `d` as a second argument to the `evaluate`.

```
async function testEv(d) {
  const data = await this.page.evaluate((c) {
    console.log('d from args is', c)
  }, d)
}
```

If you need to pass more than one argument you can pass an object

```
async function testEv(d) {
  const data = await this.page.evaluate((obj) {
    console.log('obj.foo from args is', obj.foo);
    console.log('obj.bar from args is', obj.bar);
  }, 
  {
    foo: d,
    bar: d,
  })
}
```